# Ubuntu 13.04 disconnecting issue

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Weird situation here. I can download anything I want with no problems whatsoever. As soon as I try to download a torrent via a magnet link, I disconnect from the wireless router after about three minutes. This happens in both Transmission and Deluge. It happens regardless of the torrent. It happens regardless of the site. But go find a random program or 2-hour YouTube video, and there's no problem. I just upgraded from 11.04 (clean install), and I never had this issue before. Anybody have any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Too many connection attempts in Deluge. I cut the max connections back, and it works like a charm now.